# Way to remove all non module script tags and load via SystemJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, systemjs, es6-module-loader

I am on AngularJS 1.5, Typescript, Grunt and SystemJS 
   We are incrementally migrating our files to ES6 modules. So our current implementation on index.html is we have all our vendor files as script tags along with our bundled app file (which is transpiled in "system" mode)
And as a last step, we do a system.import(sub-modules) which is part of the bundled app.js file.

Now I need to remove all of my script tags and load them via SystemJs as well. Part of my problem is, most of the vendor files are not in the module format. I want them to be loaded by SystemJS as is. Is that possible ?

index html would be:

```
  <script>jquery.min</script>
  <script>angular</script>
  <script>angular-ui-route</script>
  <script>non-modules-file.j</script>
  <script>non-modules-file2.j</script>
  <script>jquery-ui</script>
  <script>app.js</script>

  System.import('core');
  System.import('common');
```

I want to be able to remove the scripts tag and then add it to my import. Please help.

Comment: If they're not in module format, you should use `jspm` to map the paths (JSPM and SystemJS play well together, same author). Then, the modules don't even need to be in module format, System will gladly accept them. Look up jspm.io

Comment: I have already converted all my js files to ES6 module format.

Comment: I do no want to introduce jspm into the mix. It makes it more complex. I thought that SystemJS should have an option of loading script tags as is first before loading modules.

Comment: Well.. converting all your files to ES6 and then manually including _is_ complex already, JSPM helps you avoid it but in the end - it's your project and your time. If you decide to use `jspm`, you're also getting bundling/packing options out of the box which turn your humongous app into a small bundle that's also passed through rollup. But as I said, if you think it's a waste of your time, I can't really be of help. Let's hope someone with more knowledge comes along and solves it. Good luck with your project!